# how to make series in highcharts toggle between cursors

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hi I am quite new to highcharts and jquery in general and I was wondering if there was anyway to switch between cursors on series points in datatables.

For example, for my application I dont want users to click on some of the series, but I do want them to click on others

Here is a fiddle someone posted and I was wondering if I could make a function just like in the "click" that would toggle between pointers if a parameter in "this.options" was set

http://jsfiddle.net/287JP/2/

```
$(function () {
         $('#container').highcharts({
             chart: {},
             xAxis: {
                 minPadding: 0.05,
                 maxPadding: 0.05
             },

             series: [{
                 data: [{
                     x: 0,
                     y: 29.9,
                     url: 'http://www.google.com'
                 }, {
                     x: 1,
                     y: 71.5,
                     url: 'http://www.yahoo.com'
                 }]
             }],


             plotOptions: {
                 series: {
                     cursor: 'pointer',
                     point: {
                         events: {
                             click: function () {
                                 var url = this.options.url;
                                 window.open(url);
                             }
                         }
                     },
                 }
             },
         });
     });
```

Is there anyway to do something like

```
cursor: function() {
  if(this.options.clickable) {
    'pointer'
  } else {
    'default'
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking, but you could change the 'window.open(url)' to 'if (url) {window.open(url)}'...  Then in your data the lack of a url would prevent that point from opening a new window when clicked...

Comment: Yup thats good, I already used that in my code (sorry not shown in the fiddle), but for series that arent able to open a new tab I dont want the cursor to be a pointer which implies that the series is clickable. Does that make more sense? sorry its kinda hard to explain -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possibly via modifying the properties of the chart after created (in a callback for example). See this [post](http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=12758). You would do something like:

```
$.each(chart.series[0].data,function(i,point){
    if(point.options.cursorEnabled){ 
        point.graphic.attr({
            cursor:'pointer'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. however after looking at the fiddle it does not seem to work for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/veAKe/16/

Does it work for you?

Comment: @James, it does work. Note that cursor is enabled by default. For the series points where you want it as a point you need to set it to false. See http://jsfiddle.net/veAKe/1/.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `clickable` to options then in the click event check its value. If it's false, then execute `return false`. That will cancel the event.
Here's your updated code

```
$(function () {
     $('#container').highcharts({
         chart: {},
         xAxis: {
             minPadding: 0.05,
             maxPadding: 0.05
         },

         series: [{
             data: [{
                 x: 0,
                 y: 29.9,
                 url: 'http://www.google.com',
                 clickable: true
             }, {
                 x: 1,
                 y: 71.5,
                 url: 'http://www.yahoo.com',
                 clickable: false
             }]
         }],


         plotOptions: {
             series: {
                 cursor: 'pointer',
                 point: {
                     events: {
                         click: function () {
                             if(!this.options.clickable)
                                 return false;
                             var url = this.options.url;
                             window.open(url);
                         }
                     }
                 },
             }
         },
     });
 });
```

Comment: is there a way to do that in the cursor

such as

cursor: function() {
if(this.options.clickable) {
'pointer'
} else {
'default'
}